# Restrict XP machine to LAN only

Tags: windows-xp

I am running a windows xp machine on my network for legacy hardware and software. I wish to allow the xp machine to access all machines on the LAN but prevent it from having access to the internet.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: I don't see how the question title related to the body. Do you need to redirect traffic or block Internet access? Either way this should be done on the router which connects to the Internet. But this requires more information on it and your network setup.

Comment: I agree about title and body saying entirely different things. To give the box man access only, give it a static IP on your network and do not specify a default gateway.

Comment: My bad - I changed the body and forgot to change the title.

Comment: @MrMills you can still edit the question to update the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are asking for the **best** way:

1. If using DHCP to assing IPs. Configure your DHCP server to "reserve" (i.e. make it permanent) IP for that machine.
2. Configure your router which connects to the Internet to disallow access from LAN to WAN (Internet) for this particular IP. This will effectively block Internet access for that host so it can't connect to the Internet completely.

This is the only "good" way if you do not trust this machine or it's user with admin rights. Other ways suggested here, such as removing default gateway (route) will work too. But it can be "reverted" by someone who has admin access to that machine or even some malicious software running on that host.

Comment: I am the only user on the machine. Ideally, I would want to "trap" internet traffic and redirect it to a server on my LAN

Comment: Thanks - I've just restricted access to the internet in the router for that machine. It leaves the XP machine more standard.

Comment: Then specify a gateway of the server in your LAN. The difficulty is going to be hacking that server to intercept traffic not going to its IP address. You may be able to get 80% of the way there fairly easily by using a name server to serve up the targets IP for any DNS lookup.

Comment: If you don't trust the machine or its user with admin rights, this is not enough: user with admin rights can change the IP configuration to gain access to the Internet. In that case, only a separate L2 network would do.

Comment: Thanks I'll give that a go - I'm the only user on the machine so I trust it (and me).

Comment: @EsaJokinen 802.1x or some other method of authorizing & authenticating client can do this too.

Comment: @MrMills yes, if you would want to redirect your network traffic to another machine you can change it's default gateway to that machine on LAN. Or can use NAT redirection on your router if it has such feature.

Answer (score 0):

A couple ways you could do this, depending on your setup and router.

1. You can do this on the gateway/router by blocking the IP address of the XP machine (assuming it is static) or even the MAC address. Specifically you would be blocking outbound traffic coming from the XP machine.
2. You can also create state routes on the XP machine forcing any internet bound traffic to go nowhere, or to a bad gateway.
3. Lastly, you could put the XP machine behind another router and put it on a different subnet. This way you definitely control this second router and can then route only the LAN traffic to the other subnet, and block all other traffic.

Comment: Do I set the gateway in Advanced TCP/IP Settings or through cmd?

Comment: Yes under Advanced TCP/IP settings you can override the default gateway.